# How can I add (+1) date to SqlDataSource parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using "between" in my SQL query and need to subtract 1 to the StartDate and add 1 to the EndDate parameters to get accurate results.  I can do this in code but how can I accomplish the same in the `asp:SqlDataSource` control?

Example of my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ds1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxx %>" SelectCommand="SELECT SUM(oi.quantity_shipped) AS [Quantity Shipped], oi.itemDescription AS [Item Description], oi.itemLanguage, oi.item_id FROM order_items AS oi INNER JOIN orderX AS x ON oi.order_ID = x.id WHERE x.shipDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate GROUP BY oi.itemDescription, oi.itemLanguage, oi.item_id ORDER BY [Item Description]">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="BDPStartDate" Name="StartDate" PropertyName="SelectedDate" DbType="Date" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="BDPEndDate" Name="EndDate" PropertyName="SelectedDate" DbType="Date" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp

Comment: DataAdd() would be the best option   DateAdd(DAY,-1,@StartDate) and DateAdd(DAY,1,@EndDate)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks I was struggling with syntax :)